# can't get the output when I excute a .bat file in c#

Tags: c#, java, batch-file, process, java-home

I'm trying to call .bat file from c#. 
my project name is 
here's the code MaestroStart, and the batch file has the same name. they are both at the same directory.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process p = new Process();  
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;            
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\mbmteks\Maestro\MaestroStart.bat";
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\mbmteks\Maestro\MaestroStart\MaestroStart\bin\Debug";
            p.Start();

            //string output = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            textBox2.Text = output;


            p.WaitForExit();

        }
```

but this is the only output that I'm getting :
("JAVA_HOME does not point at a JDK or JRE.  Either set the JAVA_HOME environment variable or specify a JDK for your IDEA project.").
If the use this statement

```
string output = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

I got nothing on the screen.

I tried to reset the Jave-Home environment variable to all the directories that I'm working with, but nothing changes.

this is the code of the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

Set JAVA_HOME=.\jre

if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto JavaFound
echo "JAVA_HOME does not point at a JDK or JRE.  Either set the JAVA_HOME environment variable or specify a JDK for your IDEA project."
goto End

:JavaFound
if exist "start.jar" goto StartJarFound
echo "start.jar was not found.  Check your Jetty installation or your app path."
goto End

:StartJarFound
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar start.jar

:End
```

this is the output of the batch file when I run it directly:

WARNING: System properties and/or JVM args set.  Consider using --dry-run or --e
xec
2014-03-11 13:35:51.964:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.12.v20130726
2014-03-11 13:35:51.998:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\mbmteks\Maestro\webapps at interval 1
2014-03-11 13:35:52.010:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\Program
 Files (x86)\mbmteks\Maestro\webapps\ROOT
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAp
pender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFil
eAppender.
2014-03-11 13:36:00.540:INFO:ROOT:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

2014-03-11 13:36:03.274:INFO:ROOT:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springDi
spatcher'
2014-03-11 13:36:03.647:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\mbmteks\Maestro\contexts at interval 1
2014-03-11 13:36:03.671:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnect
or@0.0.0.0:9999

Is my workingdirectory correct? I mean, it should be the directory of my current project ??

Comment: "JAVA_HOME does not point at a JDK or JRE". Do you have a JDK or JRE installed?

Comment: What output do you get when executing the batch file in command line?

Comment: Can you show us the code in the batch file?

Comment: There is no logical connection between C# code and incorrect JAVA_HOME setting. First of all try tu run your bat file manually from same location as tries your .NET application.
Problem is inside bat file or in windows variables configuration for JAVA or you don't have correctly installed JRE!

Comment: This is the code of the batch file, which I didn't write.


@echo off
setlocal

Set JAVA_HOME=.\jre

if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto JavaFound
echo "JAVA_HOME does not point at a JDK or JRE.  Either set the JAVA_HOME environment variable or specify a JDK for your IDEA project."
goto End

:JavaFound
if exist "start.jar" goto StartJarFound
echo "start.jar was not found.  Check your Jetty installation or your app path."
goto End

:StartJarFound
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar start.jar


:End

Answer (score 0):

```
 //to excute bat file in java 
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c GO.BAT", null, new File("D:\\Documents and        Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\bat"));
          InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
     int i = 0;
        while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
           System.out.print((char)i);
        }
   } catch(IOException ioException) {
        System.out.println(ioException.getMessage() );
    }
```